# VBA: 1 cell to master

Tags: vba, excel

I need thousands of excel (2016) sheets indexed based on a single cell value. The workbooks only have 1 worksheet, and the data always exists in cell D2.

I'd like D2 copied to a master file in the second column, with the name of the associated file in the first. 
The individual excel files are separated into subfolders already, sometimes 5 folders deep.

I am really new to coding in general, so bonus points if you're able to explain things step by step. I'd like to follow and learn.

Thank you for helping in advanced!

edit:

The stuff I did before activated sheets, changed files, then activated other workbooks. I am lost with what to do next because I am not activating other worksheets, I am just pulling data from them. They don't even need to be opened.

The loop should call the file.
then I need to: select range> copy>call master file>activate>paste>add 1 to row count to shift selected cell down> end

but then I just have a bunch of numbers with no names, so I want to name the preceding cell the filename of the file it was pulled from. Searching for help on this only pulls up how to name a cell within a worksheet after a filename or path, where I want it the other way around, and from a different source which changes every time.

Code to loop:

```
Option Explicit

Sub deeploop()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objSubFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim wkbOpen As Workbook
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim CalcMode As Long

With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

'Change path
MyFolder = "C:\Path"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook
Set wks = ActiveSheet

For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
    For Each objFile In objSubFolder.Files
        Set wkbOpen = Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path)


'code


        wkbOpen.Close savechanges:=True
    Next objFile
Next objSubFolder

With Application
    .Calculation = CalcMode
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Learning starts with searching on search engine- example excel vba or macro how to copy ...

Comment: I've done a lot of searching already. I have a code already which can do the looping, but I don't know how to put the individual parts together, which is why I thought it would be best to ask.

Comment: Cool post that code and tell us what part are you having trouble with.

Comment: added the part to loop through my subfolders.

Comment: but I still don't get what's your goal. Could you explain it with some plain examples?

Answer (score 0):

> They don't even need to be opened

So don't open them!

And just put a formula in your active sheet that refers to the proper cell fully qualified with file path, file name and sheet name

assuming the only sheet of all your thousands of excel workbooks is named after "Sheet1", you could act as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub deeploop()
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objSubFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ifile As Long

    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Change path
    MyFolder = "C:\Path"

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)

    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B1") '<--| it suffices to reference the 'ActiveSheet' object since it belongs to 'ActiveWorkbook' by default
        For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
            For Each objFile In objSubFolder.Files

                .Offset(ifile).Value = Array(objFile.Name, "='" & objSubFolder.Path & "\[" & objFile.Name & "]Sheet1'!$D$2")
                ifile = ifile + 1

            Next objFile
        Next objSubFolder
    End With

    With Application
        .Calculation = CalcMode
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```